# Ubuntu is overheating my laptop

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, overheating

I have an HP laptop with the following specs:

- **CPU:** AMD A10-5745M APU at 2.1Ghz
- **GPU:** 8670m
- **RAM:** 8GB

It came with Windows 8 but I set it up as a dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04.

It’s really hot. It doesn’t shutdown or anything bad like that but is really annoying.

I have been reading about this and many posts say to that check what `top` returns.

Right now I’m using Google Chrome (20 tabs opened) and `top` says that it is using 100% of CPU. Seems like that could be the problem??

Another important thing to know is that Ubuntu does not detect properly my GPU and neither the RAM (it detects 6,9 GB).

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more information in order for us to help.  To start with include a bit of your top output.  Also include the error messages from your log files that show that the GPU and RAM displaying your issue.  What programs are you using to make that assumption.   Remember the kernel takes space as well as all its buffers so you might indeed have only 6.9 GB left.

Comment: Thanks for the help @mdpc and JakeGould.
I think that google chrome is the main issue. When i open it (no tabs , no pages , just plain ) top says 100% in CPU usage. Also the battery time indicator get really down.

Comment: I've experienced issues with Chrome on Ubuntu on a few occasions; this has often come down to plugins that I've installed - try removing all plugins and starting Chrome without any other tabs open, to see if the problem still occurs. Perhaps you'll find the culprit this way.

Comment: I removed every plugin installed, and also uninstalled google chrome itself but the problem is still there. I just open chrome without tabs and htop says 100% of CPU usage. Am testing with firefox and the laptop is cooler